# Test for object callability in match-case construct

Tags: python

For context, I have a function that matches keys in a dictionary to perform certain action; to match item keys, the function accepts either a sequence of keys to match, or a function that recognizes those keys.

I'm wondering if I can use the `match-case` pattern for it. I try something like:

```py
def process_fields(dataset,function,fields):
    """Apply function to selected values of a dictionary
    fields can be a list of keys whose values shall be processed, 
    or a predicate that returns True for the targeted fields."""
    
    match fields:
        case list() | set() | tuple():
            key_matcher = lambda x:x in fields
        case <what I'm looking for>:
            key_matcher=fields
    walk_items(dataset,key_matcher,function)
```

So far I've tried:

```
        case callable(function):
            key_matcher=function
```

```
        case typing.Callable(function):
            key_matcher=function
```

I can't find what I need in the official documentation. I'm I missing something or it's not doable?

Example is here to avoid too dry abstraction. Note that I'm NOT looking for alternatives to solve that particular problem, I can perfectly do it myself; I'm looking to find out if it exist a way to use that python structure in particular.

*Edit: Even though the function itself is not the focus of the post, I've added a docstring and simplified a bit to clarify the example.*

Comment: That approach doesn't make sense - you're matching on `fields`, then trying to say _"no actually forget `fields` is **`function`** callable?"_ Maybe if you had an input that was `Sequence[whatever] | Callable[[whatever], bool]` it would be reasonable to discriminate.

Comment: You're trying to use `match` as a `switch` statement. Sure, it has similarities, but it's not meant for what your trying to do. That's why you're having troubles, you're mis-using the feature.

Comment: What is `<matched_function>` supposed to be? `walk_items` doesn't tell us what the relationship between the three arguments is supposed to satisfy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood what you're trying to do but maybe this will help (if not, I'll delete it).

If you want to test if an object is Callable then:

```
from collections.abc import Callable

def func():
    pass

f = func

match f:
    case Callable():
        print("Yes it's callable")
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. I don't understand the downvotes. Little detail though, I've found out that Callable needs to be instantiated. `case Callable()`. Maybe you'd want to edit that.

Comment: @JonSG I wrote it this way because the OP asks specifically about match/case

Comment: despite the downvotes, this seems to be the not only a correct answer, but the "one and obvious way to do it".

Comment: @JonSG It won't work with `typing.Callable`.

Comment: Not only it won't work,`typing`  is not _meant_ for things to work at run time. `collections.abc` have the "abstract base classes" for varius protocols to be _used_ at runtime (unlike typing), and it is straight to the point.

Nothing on `typing`  will work with mach/case, but maybe NamedTuple - but it should not be on `typing` .

Comment: Yes, my bad. Not sure why I thought it would

Comment: @JonSG You likely used `Callable` instead of `typing.Callable` and it "appeared" to work, but it was actually a name capture (i.e. it assigned `Callable = f`). The [earlier revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78123029/1) had the same bug, which explains the downvotes (I am not the downvoter).

Comment: @AntoineGallix "_I've found out that Callable needs to be instantiated_" you have some misunderstanding here. This does not instantiate anything, instead this syntax indicates that it's a [class pattern](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#class-patterns) match.